# Ububtu 14.04 Mac Mini recovery

Tags: boot, usb, mac, iso

I have been running Ubuntu on the system for a while. After an update a couple of months back it failed to boot. I just got the time to tear into the problem. I mounted the disk on another system and was able to fsck the root and boot partitions. When I try to boot all I get is a black screen with a flashing underbar "_" The internal drive is trash. I can get my Snow Leopard disk to boot from a USB DVD player but not a Ubuntu DVD. I've tried making a bootable USB stick but when I hold down the alt/option key all I get is the word Windows under a disk icon and an arrow in a circle under that. Still no boot to the .dmg image on the USB stick. I am guessing I installed boot camp and that is where the windows crap is coming from. I would like to recover the system on the disk if possible but that is likely to require booting Ubuntu from either a DVD drive on the USB or a USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

That Windows disk in the Mac Mini boot menu is your Ubuntu image on that flash drive. For some reason, Macs recognizes non-Apple external bootable drives as Windows.

Yes, if you installed Ubuntu in an ext4 drive format, then you will need to mount that drive in another Linux OS. Both Windows and Macs do not recognize files in a drive with ext4 format.

You can also try a service like Drive Savers who are the world specialists in data recovery.